# spring boot starter test 1.4.1 - use assertj-core 3.5.x

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I want to use the latest assertj-core for Java8 (for example to assert on optionals).
I use spring-boot-starter-test 1.4.1  it comes with assertj 2.5.0 preconfigured.

I cannot use a spring boot parent pom.

How can I set up my maven project, so I exclude or overwrite version 2.5.0 with 3.5.2? I tried

- setting just the property `assertj.version`
- adding exclusions on the `starter-test dependency`
- adding exclusion on the `spring-boot-dependencies`

Update:

I am setting up a custom "test" module for all modules in my multi module project. I do not just need spring-test-starter but also some other dependencies and some test classes and rules.

This is what my project looks like:

```
my-module-root
 |-my-module-a (using test)
 |-my-module-b (using test)
 \-test (including starter-test, ... - in COMPILE scope (because this is a test library))
```

Now, when I exclude assertj-core on the test module (and include 3.5.2), the dependencies for the test module are ok.
But when I check the dependencies on the root level, I have both, assertj-core-2.5.0 and assertj-core-3.5.2 on the classpath.

Comment: Do module A and B include module test in "test" scope?. Are you sure you don't include anywhere spring-boot-starter-test except "test" module?

Comment: Yes and yes. Double checked. I will create a small sample on github to verify ...

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude it from `spring-boot-starter-test` and then add manually different version:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
                <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To verify which version is included:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | grep assertj
[INFO] \- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.5.2:test
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Thats What I meant with my second point. Already tried this. Forgot to mention something in the question